# ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libz.so': Operation not permitted

Tags: installation, zlib, ubuntu-20.10

While installing the zlib library from source code, running `make` provides the following error.

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libz.so': Operation not permitted
```

It seems like a permission error so tried with sudo but the error continued.
I am trying to install zlib in `/usr/local/zlib` instead of the default. Does this create an issue?

Comment: Please provide the exact make command that resulted in the error.

Comment: I followed as : `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zlib/` following by `make`. Here I received an error. Once this will resolve I will go for `make install`